# How to calculate between different group of rows of the same table group by 1 value

Tags: sql, date, group-by

I have table as:

```
Days      Date       numberfield
1    2020-04-09        5500055
2    2020-04-30        5500055
3    2020-04-11        5500055
55   2020-04-12        5500055
56   2020-04-13        5500055
```

And i need to export numberfields that have difference bigger then 2 days on particular dates.
Give me all numberfields that have difference in days more than two on the 11 and 12 april. 2020.

I have been tried several helps from here, not working for me.
Thank you for inputs…

There is query i tried, and work, but not optimized.

```
select a.date, b.date, a.numberfield, b.numberfield, b.days-a.days as difference from
(select numberfield, days, date from #tmp where date = '2020-04-11' ) a,
(select numberfield, days, date from #tmp where date = '2020-04-12' ) b
where a.numberfield = b.numberfield
order by 3
```

and result is:

```
date         date    numberfield    numberfield difference
2020-04-11   2020-04-12  5500055        5500055      1
2020-04-11   2020-04-12  5500065        5500065      1
2020-04-11   2020-04-12  5500075        5500075      1
2020-04-11   2020-04-12  5500085        5500085      1
2020-04-11   2020-04-12  5500095        5500095      562
```

Let me explain, at least try to explain :)
I wanna get numberfields that have unusual difference more than 1, >=2 between two days in row.

Like this one 5500095 example. 
So get me only numberfields that have difference >1

Comment: What is your database? MySQl? Sql server? also please add your expected output from the sample data.

Comment: It would be good if you include the expected result

Comment: Add in some data where the condition is not met too, so that when someone finds a solution, they can verify that it works. Add in your current SQL and it's actual result. Then add in the desired result. At present a SQL that just returns one row, any row from your sample data will in fact return a `numberfield`. I'm thinking that's not what you want.. Also, is "on particular dates" a range or distinct dates? Kindly, make your issue unambiguous and easy to understand.

Comment: i just did. thank you ppls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `join` with `where`:

```
select a.date, b.date, a.numberfield, b.numberfield,
       (b.days - a.days) as difference
from #tmp a join
     #tmp b
     on a.numberfield = b.numberfield
where a.date = '2020-04-11' and b.date = '2020-04-12' and
      abs(b.days - a.days) > 1
order by 3;
```

The subqueries are not needed . . . nor are they particularly helpful.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I tried before several different ways with having count and difference, but not working, as join and getting - twice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select numberfield
from mytable
where date in ('2020-04-11', '2020-04-12')
group by numberfield
having
    max(case when date = '2020-04-12' then days end)
        > min(case when date = '2020-04-11' then days end) + 2
```

If `days` is always increasing and `(numberfield, date)` tuples are unique, the `having` clause can be simplified as:

```
having max(numberfield) > min(numberfield) + 2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't help me. return 0. I just edited my original post, maybe that helps with my request. thank you vm